# Using "INDIRECT" function in the "SUMPRODUCT" formula for True/False Cell Reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-indirect

This is the formula that I am currently using:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((INDIRECT("A2"):INDIRECT("A"&(ROW()-1))=A359)*1)
```

It works great, but I would like to use this instead:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((INDIRECT("A2"):INDIRECT("A"&(ROW()-1))=INDIRECT("A"&(ROW())))*1)
```

Unfortunately I get a `#VALUE!`.  What am I doing wrong?  Both `INDIRECT("A"&ROW(()))` and `A359` return the same value, so I'm not sure why this won't work.

The reason I am not using a simple `COUNTIF` function is because I stripped my formula of all unnecessary components and only left the part that I am having trouble with (i.e. I need to use the `SUMPRODUCT` formula and a `COUNTIF` formula will not work)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nothing seems wrong to me, and it seems to be working fine on my machine. (Btw you could use A2 instead of `INDIRECT("A2")`) and `ROW()` instead of `(ROW())`.

Comment: I am using `INDIRECT("A2"):INDIRECT("A"&(ROW()-1))` instead of `$A$2:$A358` because I copy, paste, and delete this formula from different sheets all the time.  If I were to leave in the normal cell reference `A2`, then it would get messed up every time I moved/deleted the formula.

Comment: but INDIRECT makes your formula volatile and it recalculates each time _any_ cell in the sheet changed (and recalculation of all formulas may be time consuming).

Comment: Weird, it's not working for me.  Please see this file [link](https://app.box.com/s/uqcd0a7o846xkk1e82nc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need `INDIRECT` instead of ordinary cell references but the specific problem here is that `ROW` function returns an "array", even when it returns a single value, e.g. it returns {"x"} rather than just "x" - and in some circumstances Excel can't process that.

Try wrapping the second `ROW` function in a `SUM` function - the value doesn't change but it gets rid of the array, i.e.

`=SUMPRODUCT((INDIRECT("A2"):INDIRECT("A"&(ROW()-1))=INDIRECT("A"&SUM(ROW())))*1)`

This will eliminate #VALUE! eror while leaving the essential structure of your formula unchanged

Comment: I never realised that `ROW()` returned an array. Learned something new today! :)

Comment: @Jerry - in most cases it makes no difference so you wouldn't notice - `COLUMN` function does the same (whereas `ROWS` and `COLUMNS` do not)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((($A$2:INDEX($A:$A,ROW()-1))=INDEX($A:$A,ROW()))*1)
```

it gives you the same result.

But above formula is volatile. Instead I would use next one, say in `B3` :

```
=SUMPRODUCT((($A$2:$A2)=$A3)*1)
```